# How to set up permissions für Umbraco correctly? (Repository unavailable on install)

Tags: iis, iis-7, umbraco

I can't get an Umbraco installation set up completly. I have been running into the error:

> Oops...the installer can't connect to the repository
>
> Starter Kits could not be fetched from the repository as there was no
>   connection - which can occur if you are using a proxy server or
>   firewall with certain configurations, or if you are not currently
>   connected to the internet.  Click Continue to complete the
>   installation then navigate to the Developer section of your Umbraco
>   installation where you will find the Starter Kits listed in the
>   Packages tree.

I have tried this via manual install, Web platform installer and WebMatrix.
When I tried this wie WebPI and manual I gave the IIS_IUSRS *FULL ACCESS* to the Umbraco folder and de C:\windows\temp folder to be on the safe side. Which has brought no effect.

I have also tried using the steps described [here](http://our.umbraco.org/forum/getting-started/installing-umbraco/21171-Failed-install-skin-from-Starter-Kit) and on google.

Every option has been tested on my physcial windows 7 professional machine, as well as on my virtual Windows server 2008 R2 dev-environment with the actual Umbraco 6.0.5 build.

I am hoping you can provide me with a working solution
Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

This problem is probably caused due to the umbraco installer not being able to connect to the internet, it doesn't look like a file permission problem.

If you are behind a proxy or firewall, you could add a proxy to the web.config that will allow umbraco to connect to the repository.

```
<defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" />
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kd3cf2ex.aspx

Setting the permissions for ISS_IUSRS should work, though I would use the "IIS APPPOOL\{application-pool-name}" user to set the permissions.

A ps script is available at the bottom of the following page: http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/install-and-setup/set-umbraco-folder-permissions-from-command-line

However, if you reached the point where the installer is asking to install a package, isn't the application already running?
What happens if you quit the process, and login to umbraco?

Comment: the only thing that fails is the installation of the starter kit(s). Since I am totally new to Umbraco, I'd like to go through it step by step and don't start from scratch

Comment: the defaultproxy settings work on IISExpress (WebMatrix), but not on the standard IIS, which will be the production environment.

Comment: What do you mean they do not work on standard IIS? Something else must be wrong, asI used it both on IIS6 and 7